# Keep only nth line if keyword present

Tags: bash, awk, filtering

Assume a text file that contains lines starting with `foo` and `bar`, respectively. Assume further that I would like to print only every fourth line of the ones starting with `bar`; the lines starting with `foo` should always be printed.

```
foo bar qux
   # Deliberate empty line
bar baz 1
bar baz 2
bar baz 3
bar baz 4
bar baz 5
bar baz 6
bar baz 7
bar baz 8
# A miscellaneous code comment
```

The following code prints every fourth line irrespective of the first word and is thus not what I am looking for.

```
awk '/^bar/ NR == 1 || NR % 4 == 0' infile
```

What would the correct code be (preferentially with `awk`)?

**EDIT:**

Thanks to *fedorqui* for his excellent suggestion. Considering the potential appearance of empty lines and comments in the input file, I am using the following code:

```
user$ awk '!/^bar/ || (/^bar/ && !(++c%4))' file
foo bar qux
   # Deliberate empty line
bar baz 4
bar baz 8
# A miscellaneous code comment
```

Comment: Thanks! Note in the previous edit of my answer I missed the ^ from the regex, so the correct expression should be `awk '/^foo/ || (/^bar/ && !(++c%4))' file`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a counter:

```
awk '/^foo/ || (/^bar/ && !(++c%4))' file
```

This prints lines that accomplish either of these:

- start with "foo"
- start with "bar" and this happens for the 4th time, 8th... That is, every four times a line starts with "bar".

See it in action:

```
$ cat a
foo1
bar1
bar2
bar3
foo2
foo3
bar4
bar5
bar6
bar7
bar8
bar9
$ awk '/^foo/ || (/^bar/ && !(++c%4))' a
foo1
foo2
foo3
bar4
bar8
```

Comment: Did you forget a `c=0` or modulo? This prints the fourth bar but not the eighth, twelfth, etc.

Comment: @tripleee you are right, I thought it was just the 4th. Thanks, updated!

Comment: If the file _only_ contains lines starting with `foo` or `bar`: `awk '/bar/ && (++c%4) {next} 1' a`.

Comment: @JamesBrown ah right, I see. Good point, doing a reverse matching to grep out the _bad_ cases.

Comment: @fedorqui Clear and concise answer! Thank you.

Answer (score -3):

This should do the trick:

```
 awk '/^bar/ && NR % 4 == 0 || /^foo/' infile
```

Comment: I don't think it does, since it relies on NR, which does not have any defined relationship with the patterns

Comment: Considering the question, he needs every 4th line of the file which starts with _bar_ , not every 4th appearance of _bar_ in the beginning of the line. So I don't understand your downvote here

Comment: _I would like to print only every fourth line of the ones starting with bar_. Btw, I didn't downvote.